# Can I abuse OCaml Tactics in Coq to generate LaTeX from type definitions?

Tags: latex, ocaml, coq, dependent-type, coq-tactic

I'm currently looking for a way to generate LaTeX inference-rules (horizontal line style) from inductive definitions in some dependently typed language, probably Coq.

I've found [this package](https://github.com/olydis/coq2latex), but it seems pretty fragile, doesn't have a lot of recent updates, and fails silently whenever it hits unicode.

What I'm wondering is, could I abuse Coq's ability to write Tactics in OCaml to inspect an `Inductive` definition, and format it to LaTeX? Obviously I'd write the formatting code myself, but I'm wondering how to get at an AST representation

There are some plugin intro tutorials [here](http://gallium.inria.fr/blog/your-first-coq-plugin/) and [here](https://github.com/mattam82/Constructors), but they only give basics, and I haven't found true documentation of the plugins API, so I'm not sure how to get at an OCaml representation of the inductive type from, for example, the name of the type, or a goal of that type.

Has this been done? Are there existing tools that do this, or something similar, that I could use as an example?

Comment: Yes you could use LTAC to do that, but it will be painful. Your life will be easier using some metaprogramming plugin (I recommend MetaCoq), then you should be able to use Gallina to output towards your latex language. Another useful tool is coq-serapi (disclaimer I am the main author), it will provide you a serialized represenation of terms, but it is quite experimental. In fact, I am writing a TeX output engine in my spare time. A last thing to consider is that Coq actually has 3 internal term representation + the "generic argument" mechanism which can be used to embed arbitrary terms.

Comment: @ejgallego Yeah, I figured LTac wouldn't quite be up to the task, which is why I was interested in the OCaml plugins for writing tactics.

Comment: IMHO you don't want to write a plugin, but to use some existing one such as the two I've mentioned.

Comment: Now that you mention it, here's an example on how to get the information for an inductive type: https://github.com/ejgallego/coq-serapi/blob/master/serapi/serapi_protocol.ml#L462 It will return something of type https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/trunk/kernel/declarations.mli#L171 `mutual_inductive_body`. Good luck with it! It is one of the most complex types in the kernel, but basic things such as extracting the constructors are doable. Printing code https://github.com/coq/coq/blob/trunk/printing/printmod.ml#L85 may help to understand the fields.

Comment: You can indeed go to https://x80.org/rhino-hawk/ , wait for it to load, then type `(Control (StmAdd () "Require Import Coq.Init.Prelude."))` then `(Query () (Inductive "and"))` and you will see the low-level definition of a Coq Inductive type.

Comment: @ejgallego Thanks for all your help, since it looks like nobody is answering, if you sum up your comments I'll accept them as an answer

Comment: no worries, I will eventually get to make my printer truly implement the Coq -> LaTeX code, I'll post my solution in the answer section then.

Comment: Not sure about your special requirement, but ever tried Isabelle/HOL? But not dependently typed.